# How to combine parts of two sculpted heads together to create a new head?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, sculpting, photorealism

[image]

On the screenshot, there are actually two heads in the same coordinate. In the sculpting mode, the selected head (or **head 1**) is in the yellow color, whereas the unselected head (or **head 2**) is in the darker-yellow color. Apparently, these two heads have different facial features.

Now, how do I combine these two heads to form a new head? 
**Requirement**: 
I) The new head must have the eye sockets, the nose and the ears from the head 1, and have the cheek and mouth from the head 2. 
II) And the connection between the meshes should be seamless.

**Difficulty**: 
I have tried to use the FaceSet brush from Blender 2.93, and it seems not convenient to use. For example, after using it to define a new FaceSet which contains the eye sockets and nose from head 1, I don't know how to replicate the **exact** area of this new FaceSet to contain the eye sockets and nose from head 2, so that I can delete the exact area on the head 2. If the replicated area is not exact, then the two meshes are not matching, and this causes a giant seam on the new head after using the Boolean modifier to union the two meshes. Removing any big seam could actually alter and ruin the mesh of the new head.

Furthermore, even if the two meshes are almost exact matched, I still do not know the most **non-invasive** method to make the connection between the meshes seamless. If the method is invasive, like an invasive surgery, then the beautiful face is ruined by the surgery knife. Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an easy task, you will need some manual adjust, but I would try 2 different approaches:

1. add to head 1 a shrinkwrap modifier, targeting head 2 and limiting its action to a vertex group of cheeks and lips (you will probably loose some details, expecially in the inner mouth area). Apply the modifier when satisfied.
2. delete all unuseful vertices of both heads, then do a complete retopology of the character (you will have to find a working method to combine two different normal maps, to get details back).

Comment: The first approach works for me! My model does not have any normal maps or skin texture, but if it does have, then I believe that I may need some image editing software to combine two texture or maps together. By the way, on the Shrinkwrap modifier, it seems that selecting "Nearest Surface Point" on the "Wrap Method" gives the best result than any other options.